# How set multiple text message in Pushwoosh Android

Tags: php, android, notifications, pushwoosh

I am new to Pushwoosh library, I want to set two different message in the notification.

I am attaching the Image, in image instead of **Trendin**, I want custom message.

And **"Trendin"** is by default is set in pushwoosh.

I have to override the default setting.

I am sending the data to pushwoosh in JSON format, like this

```
$notifications_json = '{
                    "send_date": "now",
                    "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta",
                    "ignore_user_timezone": true,
                    "content": "'.$strMessage.'",
                    "minimize_link": "0",
                    "campaign" : "8E440-770CE",
                    "platforms": [
                        3
                    ],
                    "preset": "",
                    "link": "",
                    "devices": [
                        "'.$strHardwareID.'"
                    ],
                    "android_vibration": "1",
                    "android_gcm_ttl": "60",
                    "android_sound": "",
                    "android_header": "",
                    "android_icon": "'.$strLink.'",
                    "android_custom_icon": "'.$strLink.'",
                    "android_banner" :"'.$strImagePath.'",
                    "data":{
                        "url":"'.$strLink.'"
                    }
                }';
```

Please tell me, how can I send my own custommessage.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the text in "android_header" parameter.